# how to check if a directory does "not exist" in Makefile? if [ ! -d ... ] returns always true

Tags: makefile

I want to add a couple of lines so that the make process can error out if certain directory (set by a Makefile variable DIR1) doesn't exist. Here is the added part but this errors out even if I the directory set by DIR1 exists. For example, I made the directory called 'dir1' but make errors out. What is wrong?

```
DIR1 = dir1

.PHONY : check_dir

$(info DIR1 = $(DIR1))

check_dir:  
    if [ ! -d $(DIR1) ]; then \
        $(error "DIR1 does not exist! check Makefile!"); \
    fi
```

This is the run result.(I have directory called `dir1` in current directory).

```
> ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testmake/test1$ make  
> DIR1 = dir1 Makefile:8:
> *** "DIR1 does not exist! check Makefile!".  Stop.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$(error ...)` is systematically expanded by make before passing the recipe to the shell. So the error is raised each time this recipe is run, independently from the result of you shell `if` statement.

Use only shell constructs:

```
check_dir:  
    if [ ! -d "$(DIR1)" ]; then \
        echo "$(DIR1) does not exist! check Makefile!"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
```

Or (a bit more compact, if not easier to understand):

```
MESSAGE := $(DIR1) does not exist! check Makefile!
check_dir:  
    @[ -d "$(DIR1)" ] || { echo "$(MESSAGE)"; exit 1; }
```

There are other possibilities like:

```
check_dir: $(DIR1)

$(DIR1):
    $(error $(DIR1) does not exist! check Makefile!)
```

But this does not make a difference between a file named `$(DIR1)` and a directory.

Note: if you want to raise an error when make parses the Makefile and discovers the directory does not exist, you can use the `shell` function and a make conditional:

```
OK := $(shell if [ -d $(DIR1) ]; then echo "ok"; fi)

ifeq ($(OK),)
$(error $(DIR1) does not exist! check Makefile!)
endif
```

Comment: oh sorry, that if part was not the prerequisite. it was raised to the upper line by the stackoverflow editor. i'll fix it.

Comment: your first suggention gives me : ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testmake/test1$ make
DIR1 = dir1
if [ ! -d dir1 ]; then \
 echo "dir1 does not exist! check Makefile!"); \
 exit 1; \
fi
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting "fi")
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'check_dir' failed
make: *** [check_dir] Error 2.   maybe putting exit inside if ~ fi doesn't work? I'm sorry but can you it yourself?(if you have spare time)

Comment: Inside a recipe, obviously this could be simplified to just `[ -d "$(DIR1") ]` (notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable))

Comment: Renaud, and your second suggestion gives me : make: 'dir1' is up to date.

Comment: Renaud, the third method surely works. I guess the `if [ -d .. ]` is only for bash and not Makefile. (I saw somewhere on SO it's like also for Makefile.. Hm..) Thanks!

Comment: @ChanKim Sorry about the trailing `)`  at the end of `echo...` in my first suggestion. This was a typo that I just fixed.

Comment: @ChanKim With the second solution I suggest, if `$(DIR1)` exists, you will get `make: 'dir1' is up to date` because make tells you that there is nothing to be done for `dir1`. This is normal. It is only if it does not exist that you will get the error.

Comment: @ChanKim The third solution uses the standard `test` shell builtin (`[ -d ... ]`) and works with the default shell used by make (the bourne shell). It should work with any variant of the bourne shell (ksh, bash, zsh...)

Comment: @tripleee Yes, you're right about the quotes, of course. I fixed this, thanks. But the simplification you suggest (`[ -d "$(DIR1") ]`) would not print the error message. So it would have to be `[ -d "$(DIR1") ] || echo ...` anyway. But then the recipe would no fail and we would need to add something else. Not sure it's easier to understand for beginners. I'll suggest it as an alternative.

Comment: What I often do is put a comment above the check so that it's clearly visible in the transcript what failed. Making `make` print additional diagnostics is rarely worth the effort.